# Script execution with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have read in several places that scripts are not executed when we use React `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to insert a html fragment.

However I just tried to insert this:

```
<img src= "img.png" onload="alert('picture loaded')" alt="script test">
```

And the alert was triggered.

That doesn't really surprise me (that's why I did the test in the first place), but I'd like to better understand what we mean by "scripts don't execute".

My questions:

- apart from my example above, are there other types of scripts that
  will execute?
- is there a way to fully prevent script execution,
  including those embedded in html event handlers like in my example?
- if a script tag defines a function, will that function still be
  loaded and be callable later?
- any other behavior I should be aware of?

[Edit] I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`in a function component:

```
const htmlString = '<img src="img.png" onload="alert('picture loaded')" alt="script test">'
```

In the return statement (JSX):

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlString}} />
```

Comment: How are you inserting this?

Comment: Ihave added some more info to the post. Hopefully the answer doesn't depend on how dangerouslySetInnerHTML isused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scripts that "will not execute" are script *tags*, like `<script>`. See here for an example:

```js
const html = `
<script>console.log('this does NOT run');<\/script>
<img src onerror="console.log('but this will')">
`;
const App = () => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />;
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Inline handlers, not being `<script>` tags, *can* run, if the event they're attached to fires. (Above, an `<img>` tag with a `src` property but no valid path throws an error, so its `onerror` inline handler runs)

There are no other categories of scripts that will run in combination with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (unless an inline handler itself injects a `<script>` by other means, like with `document.createElement('script')`).

> is there a way to fully prevent script execution, including those embedded in html event handlers like in my example?

You'll need to remove the `on-` attributes. If all `on-` attributes are removed, no events which may be fired will ever result in unexpected scripts running. You could sanitize the input by sending it through DOMParser first:

```js
const sanitize = (input) => {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
  for (const elm of doc.querySelectorAll('*')) {
    for (const attrib of elm.attributes) {
      if (attrib.name.startsWith('on')) {
        elm.removeAttribute(attrib.name);
      }
    }
  }
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
};

const html = `
<div>
  <script>console.log('this does NOT run');<\/script>
  <img src onerror="console.log('but this will')">
  more content
  <style type="text/css"> img {float: left; margin: 5px}</style> 
</div>
`;
const App = () => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitize(html)}} />;
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f117a950c689d3d6ec459885a908166e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

> if a script tag defines a function, will that function still be loaded and be callable later?

No, because the `<script>` tag will not have run at all, so nothing that goes on inside of it will do anything; functions defined inside will not become visible. For such a thing to occur, you'd have to [deliberately reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) the newly injected `<script>` tag somehow, in a manner that gets it to run.

Comment: Quick question, out of curiosity: could the sanitize method also remove the scripts?

Comment: You can use `if (elm.tagName === 'SCRIPT') elm.remove();`

Comment: fyi my IDE was not happy with the for loops (says not arrays) and I had to write them differently.

Comment: For some reason, the sanitize function is also wiping out an inline style element in my test.

Comment: That sound weird, styles aren't set with `on` properties, I thought? What markup are you using?

Comment: No, not at all. It's something like <style type="text/css"> img {float: left; margin: 5px;}</style>

Comment: It looks to be applied properly to me, see edit to snippet in answer

Comment: ok, it must be something else on my end. Thanks again!

Comment: I found the issue (not the resolution): DOMParser puts the style tag in the head of doc, not in the body. I was testing on the new MS Edge. My test has style as the first tag in the string.

Comment: I was able to make it work, I used createContextualFragment instead of DOMParser.